# Conditonal component still renders - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning react and wanted to try creating a loading component that shows a loading text until a condition is met i.e. the props has the correct information.

The problem is that the element is still loading even if the condition is not met:

Leading Component:

```
    import React from 'react';

    const Loading = ({ condition, children }) => (<div>{condition ? children :
 'Loading'}</div>);       

    export default Loading;
```

Here is my render method for a component that uses the Loading Component:

```
return 
(<Loading condition={props.data && props.data.result && props.data.result.length > 1}> 
<div> { ViewHelper.getCatalogItems(props.data) }</div></Loading>);
```

Now my problem is I'm getting an error when calling `{ ViewHelper.getCatalogItems(props.data) }` becauuse props.data is undefined however I was hoping that the Loading Component wouldn't call the function if the ternary condition in the LoadingComponent was false.

if I change ViewHelper.getData to just some string value, everything seems to work and 'Loading ' is displayed.

Thanks

Comment: `ViewHelper.getCatalogItems(props.data)` is that meant to be called there, or should you be using an arrow function?

Comment: I want it to 'map' a bunch of items for a table. I think I want to call it there if the data is available i.e. the loading condition resolves to true

Comment: And you want to render the result?

Comment: only if the data is available. So if props.data is not undefined, then I want to call the function. I was hoping the loading coponent would determine whether to call it by using a ternary but it seems to call it all the same.

Comment: The problem is that you're calling with `props.data` regardless of whether it's defined or not. Can you post your `getCatalogItems` function?

Comment: That's the problem, even if I have a "throw" in getCatalogItems as the first statement, as far as I know it shouldn't throw an error because I wouldn't be calling the function if props.data is undefined and for now it always is.

Comment: You're calling the function irrespective of the condition though. If you add an if statement it should work.

Comment: a ternary doesn't work? The ternary is in the Loading component. The whole reason I want to do this, is to prevent myself from having to call the if statement for all the controls that need that data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178894/discussion-between-colin-and-eitan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that `Loading` component doesn't use `children` doesn't mean that children aren't rendered. Otherwise there would be nothing to pass as `props.children` to parent component.

As can be seen in [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vccekk), child expression is evaluated despite `children` prop ignored in parent component.

A proper way to handle this and prevent eager children rendering is to use [render prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) recipe, which is also known as [function as a child](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html#using-props-other-than-render):

```
const Loading = ({ condition, children }) => (
  <div>{condition && children ? children() : 'Loading'}</div>
);       

...

<Loading condition={props.data && props.data.result && props.data.result.length > 1}>
  {() => (
    <div> { ViewHelper.getCatalogItems(props.data) }</div>
  )}
</Loading>
```

Notice that since `props.children` is a function, it's used as `children()` in ternary expression.

Or use a HOC for components:

```
const withLoading = (Comp) =>
  ({ condition, ...props }) => (
    <div>{condition ? <Comp {...props} /> : 'Loading'}</div>
  )      
);

...

const LoadingCatalogItemsComponent = withLoading(CatalogItemsComponent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer: as estus points out below, render props are probably a good way to do this. Here's an example:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Loading = ({ condition, render }) => {
  if (condition) {
    return render();
  } else {
    return "Loading";
  }
};

const Thing = ({ data }) => {
  console.log(data);
  return data.map(d => <li>{d}</li>);
};

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [1, 2, 3]
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Loading
        condition={this.state.data.length > 1}
        render={() => {
          return <Thing data={this.state.data} />;
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/q7onlkn5j9).

Comment: I tried that and still getting the undefined error. Why is cloning the child components a better? Like I said, I'm really new to this :/

Answer (score 1):

1. the children parameter received in the Loading component will have already rendered in the parent (try logging the content of children from Loading)
2. getCatalogItems will be called regardless of the conditional

cases where props.data need to be handled here. there are multiple ways to do this:

- [defaultProps or type checking in general](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)
- input validation for getCatalogItems
- [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [default function parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

Comment: The real reason I want to do this is to prevent myself having to write null checks for props.data for a bunch of different controls on the page. I could add a null check or destructuring or defaults but then I'd have to keep doing it for every control that needs the data and then show loading , etc.

Answer (score 1):

As [@estus said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52048346/5812047), HOCs and render props are two popular methods. Moving:

```
<div>{ ViewHelper.getCatalogItems(props.data)}</div>
```

into its own component (which is passes the prop, e.g., `<CatalogItems {...props} />`) will also stop you from getting errors. As long as the code isn't in the actual render method; otherwise, it's fired, regardless of whether React would have actually rendered it.

*Example:*

```js
const Loading = ({ condition, children }) => (
  <div>{condition ? children : "Loading in 3 seconds"}</div>
);

// now that it's in its own component the code isn't run until the component actually renders
const CatalogItems = ({ data }) => data.result.map(item => item);

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: null
  };

  // dummy API call
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(
      () => this.setState({ data: { result: ["cat ", "dog ", "mouse "] } }),
      3000
    );
  }

  render() {
    const props = this.state; // let's just pretend these were inherited props

    return (
      <Loading
        condition={
          props.data && props.data.result && props.data.result.length > 1
        }
        data={props.data}
      >
        <CatalogItems {...props} />
      </Loading>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<div id='root'></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.3.1/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.3.1/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Or just `<CatalogItems data={props.data} />` if you don't want to pass every prop.